# Solution of the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am trying to solve the following PDE:

$\begin{cases} r^2u_{rr}+ru_r+u_{\varphi\varphi}=0, 
 \\ u(1,\varphi)=cos^3\varphi, & u(0,\varphi)<\infty
 \\ u(r,\varphi+2\pi)=u(r,\varphi)
 \end{cases}$

My idea is to use the Fourier method.
By using the substitution $r\frac{d}{dr}=\frac{d}{dz}\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dz}=\frac{dr}{dz}\frac{d}{dr}$, from which we can deduce:

$\frac{dr}{dz}=r\Rightarrow r=e^z$

My question is, is it now enough to use the Fourier method with the given boundary conditions, i.e. 
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\alpha_k(r)U(\varphi)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Following your suggestion, you can write the solution as
>   $\ds{\mrm{a}\pars{r}\cos\pars{\varphi} + \mrm{b}\pars{r}\cos\pars{3\varphi}}$ because $\ds{\cos^{3}\pars{\varphi}}$ is a linear combination of $\ds{\cos\pars{\varphi}}$ and $\ds{\cos\pars{3\varphi}}$. That yields simple differential equations for $\ds{\mrm{a}\pars{r}}$ and $\ds{\mrm{b}\pars{r}}$.

Hereafter, I'll try the *general method* ( it starts from the general solution ).

The $\ds{2D}$-*Laplace equation general solution*, in polar coordinates, is given by:
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{r,\varphi} & =
\pars{A\varphi + B}\bracks{C\ln\pars{r} + D} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{a_{n}\sin\pars{n\varphi + \alpha_{n}}r^{n} + b_{n}\sin\pars{n\varphi + \beta_{n}}{1 \over r^{n}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\ds{A, B, C, D, \braces{a_{n}},\braces{b_{n}},\braces{\alpha_{n}},\braces{\beta_{n}}}$ are *constants*. Since
$\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{r,\varphi + 2\pi} = \mrm{u}\pars{r,\varphi}}$, $\ds{A = 0}$ and, in such case, I can perform the scales $\ds{BC \mapsto C}$ and
$\ds{BD \mapsto D}$. Then, \eqref{1} is reduced to
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{r,\varphi} & =
C\ln\pars{r} + D +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{a_{n}\sin\pars{n\varphi + \alpha_{n}}r^{n} + b_{n}\sin\pars{n\varphi + \beta_{n}}{1 \over r^{n}}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{0,\varphi} < \infty \implies C = 0\ \mbox{and}\ b_{n} = 0\
\forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}}$. 
Also, $\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{1,\varphi} = \cos^{3}\pars{\varphi} =
{3 \over 4}\,\cos\pars{\varphi} + {1 \over 4}\,\cos\pars{3\varphi}}$ and

\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{1,\varphi} & =
D + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin\pars{n\varphi + \alpha_{n}}
=
D + a_{1}\sin\pars{\varphi + \alpha_{1}} + 
a_{3}\sin\pars{3\varphi + \alpha_{3}}
\\[2mm] &
+ \sum_{{\large n = 2} \atop
{\large n \not= 3}}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin\pars{n\varphi + \alpha_{n}}r^{n}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\mbox{Set}\qquad D = 0\,;\quad \alpha_{1} = 
\alpha_{3} = -\,{\pi \over 2}\,;\quad
-a_{1}  = {3 \over 4}\,,\quad -a_{3}  = {1 \over 4}
\\ &
\mbox{and}\qquad a_{n} = b_{n} = 0\,,\quad n = 2,4,5,6,\ldots
\end{align}

---

The *final solution* becomes:
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{r,\varphi} & =
{3 \over 4}r\cos\pars{\varphi} + {1 \over 4}\,r^{3}\cos\pars{3\varphi}
\end{align}